# Entity Framework 6: Multiple contexts from same database in 1 transaction

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

With 2 different context classes which use the same database what is the best way include changes to both in the same transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) for distributed transaction. Concept:

```
using(var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
   using (var context1 = new DbContext1())
   {
      ...
      context1.SaveChanges();
   }

   using (var context2 = new DbContext2())
   {
      ...
      context2.SaveChanges();
   }

   transaction.Complete();
}
```

Only when TransactionScope is completed (committed), changes will reflect in database.

Comment: I've clarified in the question that the 2 contexts are separate classes. I didn't make that clear.

Comment: My answer will work with separate classes. Even with separate databases.